# Health Effects of Drinking Slowly

Tags: health, drinking

I really like the flavor of dark beer, but I hate getting buzzed. Thus, I have developed the habit of drinking a single beer over the course of 1-3 days, because then I can keep my BAC low (ie. sub 0.01%). I am curious if the health effects of drinking slowly differ from drinking fast and intermittently.

For example, will the following have different health effects and how?

- 1 beer drunk in 10 min every day
- 1 beer drunk in 8 hours every day

Comment: I kind of doubt you’ll find any scientific studies on this.

Answer (score 4):

Its very well documented how alcohol effects the body, or should I say how its processed. The variable in question here is the rate at which you consume it.

If you drink one beer in 10 minutes then most likely (depending on percentage of alcohol the drink contains) you will feel a 'buzz' because you would be consuming alcohol faster than your body can break it down.
If you drink one beer over 1-3 days, your body should be able to break it down without you feeling buzzed.

Prolonged alcohol use, whether you feel the 'buzz' or not, can lead to deficiencies in certains vitamins and minerals in addition to the extra load you are placing on your liver and kidneys which contributes to their decline of function over time versus someone who never drinks alcohol.

Note, there are a lot of variables here so this is general advice.